# Authy register user without providing email and phone number

Tags: twilio, authy

I am investigating Twilio Authy for push authentication. Due to organizational policy we wont be able to provide user mobile no or email at the time of registration. Hence I was looking into "Add a user without providing email or phone number" section of your documentation. 
If I understand correctly
1. We have to call Authy to get a JWT
2. Get a QR code string
3. Present QR code
4. User should use Authy app to scan QR code

We dont want use to use Authy app to do step 4. We want that to happen within our own app. Does SDK support for this or can this only app via Authy App.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any solution till now ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[The Authy SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/twilioauth-sdk) does not currently support the [QR code/no PII method of registering users with Authy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#add-a-user-without-providing-email-or-phone-number). When you generate the QR code with the JWT, the Authy application itself then registers the user with your Authy application using the JWT as an authorization token.

You will either need to use the Authy app and use the QR code method or provide an email and phone number when registering your user and use the Authy SDK.

If you feel neither of these are appropriate I recommend you talk to [Twilio sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) about your use case.